# django - how to check if email is already exists

Tags: python-3.x, django

I need to show error message if email is already exists, but I can't check if new customer trying to enter used email.

I am using UserChangeForm.

forms.py

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('email', 'fname', 'lname', 'phone','bday', 'country', 'gender','picture')
        
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    phone = PhoneNumberField(widget=PhoneNumberPrefixWidget(initial='GE'), required=False)
    phone.error_messages['invalid'] = 'Incorrect international code or Phone number!'    


    
    
    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request, id):
    account = Account.objects.all()
    user = Account.objects.get(id=id)
    form = UserChangeForm(instance=user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=user)
        for info in account:
            if info.email == form.email:
                messages.warning(request, 'email already exists.')
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.is_active = True
            data.save()

            return redirect('account:editprofile', id)

    context = {'form':form, 'user':user}
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context)
```

html

```
<div class="form-div-container">
     <label class="label label-padding">Email</label>
     {% render_field form.email class="form-control form-control-edit" %}
</div>
{% if messages %}
     {% for message in messages %}
           <div class="alert alert-info display-flex align-items-center for-alert" role="alert">
                <p class="alert-p"></p>{{ message }}</p>
           </div>
     {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
```

I saw some examples but they don't work in my case as I do.

Also, I find out form.errors but I didn't like it.

I tried my way in views but it didn't work also

So, I hope you will help me.

Comment: What kind of error messages are you getting with this?

Comment: I don't get any type of error, it is just not working. I can't show error message with html

Comment: Show what you have in the html as well bro...

Comment: So your able to sign up as many people with the same email as you want?

Comment: No, I am not able to use the same email as many time as I want, but I want to show error message when they enter the same email what is used on the other account because customer should know why he can't register or edit profile.

in this case customer editing profile

Comment: I'd suggest you try printing out something where `if info.email == form.email:` is met. So above `messages.warning(request, 'email already exists.')` just `print('Email already exist')`. Please tell if you're seeing that there as a result in the console.

Comment: it is not printing and it is what I am saying, it is not working at all.

before I posted here I tried different ways with print function but I could not get what I wanted to do.

Comment: Okay, nice. One last request here... Try `print(form.email)` above `for info in account:`. Tell me if that gives a value in console.

Comment: form.email or info.email? I have tried it below form.is_valid but it didn't print anything, but when I changed and tried below     if request.method == "POST":
it printed emails. But when I tried to check >>             if info.email == form.email:
I got error. >> 'UserChangeForm' object has no attribute 'email'

Comment: I added error in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to extract the email value from the form and run it against the `Accounts queryset` to check if it exist...

You can try this...

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request, id):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=id)

    # context['DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE'] = settings.DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE
    user = Account.objects.get(id=id)
    form = UserChangeForm(instance=user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            post_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email') # Extracting the email value from the form
            if Account.objects.filter(email=post_email).exists():
                if str(account) == str(post_email):
                    print('okokok')
                    data = form.save(commit=False)
                    data.is_active = True
                    data.save()
                    messages.warning(request, "Personal data succesfully updated.")
                    return redirect('account:editprofile', id)

            else:
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.is_active = True
                data.save()
                messages.warning(request, "Personal data succesfully updated.")
                return redirect('account:editprofile', id)
        else:
            post_email = form.data.get('email') # Extracting the email value from the form
            if Account.objects.filter(email=post_email).exists():
                if str(account) != str(post_email):
                    messages.warning(request, "Email already exists")

                    # return redirect('account:editprofile', id)


    context = {'form':form, 'user':user}
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', context)
```

`.exists()` on the queryset is what returns `True` or `False` in this case.

What I have overlooked was your `forms.py`. Please add a widget to give the `email field` a `name attribute` where you can refer to it to use it's value from the form.

```
class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ('email', 'fname', 'lname', 'phone','bday', 'country', 'gender','picture')
    widgets = {
        email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'name':'email', 'class':'form-control'})),
    }
```

This worked for me just now...

Comment: Answer was updated bro... Check out the `Class Meta` details.

Comment: I have tried but again is not working :(
I tried like you said and also I tried in my email widget but no reaction if email is already exists.

Comment: It worked well for me, so I'm not sure now why it's not working for you.

Comment: I don't know what's going on and why is not working for me, but anyway, thank you for your try.

Comment: Link me up in this chat bro... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234540/python-and-django-help I think I'd love to view your code...

Comment: I cant text you before I have 20 reputation point :( if you have discord send me the name and ID and I will be able to add and show you my whole codes.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the model level by making the email field unique, if you do that the `ModelForm` will add uniqueness validation automatically.

And for form validations in general, you should put all validations in the form itself, so that when you call `form.is_valid()` you get the cleaned data if data is valid.

I recommend you to read Django documentation on [forms and fields validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).